# Navigation in one page view

Tags: navigation, ios

I am trying to design an ecommerce iOS app. I want to show the list of categories, sub categories and the products in just one screen so that I don't have to navigate from one screen to another.

The app has around 10 categories followed by 6 sub categories followed by n no. of products.

For iOS apps, drop down is generally not suggested from what I have researched. Plus, with so many products, I don't think drop down will be a good idea.

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this ?

Comment: It's still a bit vague, but I've added content from your comments into the post and reopened for now as there is more detail here than previously.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the details you provided, i would suggest a tableview with a cell containing a switch that toggles the category or sub category. After a change in the category and sub category update to the main list of products. The concept is similar to the settings page -> cellular data